# Oracle SQL Developer's result grid loading on demand

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

If you send a query from SQL Management Studio you will often add the equivalent of `where rownum < 10` to prevent huge result tables to be loaded into the result grid.

In Oracle's SQL Developer this is not required. The grid will be populated only while you keep scrolling. You can query one day and start scrolling the next day if you do not interrupt the connection.

It seems that Oracle's implementation of maintaining a state where you can access the results lazily over a long period of time is not heavy on the client.

Is it heavy on the server under some circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on how Oracle implements their read consistency.  Combined with the fact the Oracle drivers do some amount of caching on the client behind the scenes is what your seeing.  Link: [Data Concurrency and Consistency](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c21cnsis.htm)

It's not heavy on the front end in the sense that Oracle isn't loading all the data at once. It can be taxing on the server if you have a lot of large unprocessed queries going on at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be heavy on the server (i.e. just runs the query like any other tool). It will be heavy on the client in the sense that the more data you load into the grid, the more client memory it will consume.  You can easily check this on a Windows PC using Task Manager.  Open up Task Manager and select the Processes tab, then find your SQL Developer process e.g.
[image]

Now start scrolling through the data grid results on a large table.  If you go back to Task Manager you will see the memory usage of SQL Developer has gone up.

If you dare, press Ctrl+End in the data grid and it will scroll right through to the end (this may take some time).  Monitor the memory usage in Task Manager and it will jump up every now and then.

I have just been doing this, and I thought that if I then closed the data grid tab the memory would be released, but that doesn't appear to be the case (though perhaps it is marked for garbage collection - I don't know).  If I then open the data grid on a another table and scroll through, the memory usages continues on its upward path (I've got to 750MB so far, grid is still scrolling...)

It could be that after closing a grid the memory is released eventually (I will report back if/when I find out) but otherwise probably best to close SQL Developer and restart after doing this.

**UPDATE**
Once my query finished the memory usage was up to 900MB.  I then closed the data grid, and the memory immediately dropped to 892MB (i.e. not much).  I then left it for 15 minutes and used my PC for other tasks; SQL Dev's memory usage stayed unchanged.  So it seems best to close and restart SQL Dev after performing very large queries in data grids.

Comment: I never bothered to look at memory usage.  I always assumed when you closed the results pane, it would release any memory.  I wonder what the Java Garbage collector is waiting for?  Unless they are managing memory internally.

Comment: When you load all the data into the grid things are trivial. The Server is done and the client memory is full because the grid does not hold only data but lots of other stuff too, like dirty flags, colors, fonts, referenes etc... But that was not my question.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg: sorry, in that case I'm not sure what you were asking.  Are you asking how the server remembers where you got to in the query?

Comment: @TonyAndrews, that and more. I think there is quite a lot that the server must do/remember to keep a lazy read alive. I would assume this is expensive on the server. A further support for this assumption is that the Sql Server Management Studio does not provide this feature. On the other hand this use case happens very often and maybe Oracle found a way to make it cheap.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg, I would imagine that SQL Server tries to prevent long-running queries because they block other sessions from writing; in Oracle this is not the case: your query can take as long as it likes without affecting other sessions (though if it takes too long it may fail when it can no longer find the stale data it needs).